# How do i add hyperlinks to my existing table cells

Tags: c#, hyperlink

I have added a hyperlink to my existing Table cells but I get the filmname twice. Also i want to add other table cells as hyperlinks like Directors, Actors and Filmyear. how do i do that?

**My Table Cells below:**

```
            tc = GetTableCell(film.FilmName);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

            tc = GetTableCell(film.Directors[0].PersonName);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

            tc = GetTableCell(film.Actors[0].PersonName);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

            tc = GetTableCell(film.FilmYear);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
```

**My HyperLink code below:**

```
 HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
            link.NavigateUrl = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/";
            link.Text = film.FilmName;


            tc.Controls.Add(link);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `GetTableCell`? Where are you using HyperLink code?

Comment: You should replace `tc = GetTableCell(film.FilmName);` with `tc = new TableCell();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 private void CreateTable()
 {
    Table table = new Table();

    TableRow tr = new TableRow();

    //film name
    tr.Cells.Add(GetTableCell("Film Name"));

    //director
    tr.Cells.Add(GetTableCell("Director Name"));

    //actor
    tr.Cells.Add(GetTableCell("Actor Name"));

    //film year
    tr.Cells.Add(GetTableCell("Film Year"));

    //film link
    HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
    link.NavigateUrl = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/";
    link.Text = "Film Name";

    tr.Cells.Add(GetTableCell(link));    

    table.Rows.Add(tr);
}

//returns new table cell with text content
private TableCell GetTableCell(string text)
{
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    tc.Text = text;

    return tc;
}

//returns new table cell with hyperlink
private TableCell GetTableCell(HyperLink link)
{
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    tc.Controls.Add(link);

    return tc;
}
```